# How to stop program running infinite loop on close GUI (java)

Tags: java, swing, sockets, termination, windowlistener

I have a simple program for server/client communication using sockets.
The server class contains `run()` method, this method has infinite loop to wait for socket acceptance.

Any way, I wrote a code in the constructor to do termination for processing on close,

```
 this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        System.out.println("Close operation server done");
        toClient.println("Bye");
        closeStreams();
        socket = null;
        serverSocket = null;
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

When I read the API for the [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) `windowClosing(WindowEvent e)` it says:

> Invoked when a window is in the process of being closed. The close
>   operation can be overridden at this point.

It says **when** a window is in the process of being closed. But the loop inside the run() method still gaining the control, and will not finish due to the logic of the program, so the window will not be closed (actually the GUI is closed) but the processing is still working behind the scenes.

**Update:**

the `run()` method:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            idle = true;
            System.out.println("System is running");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted on server side");
            openStreams();
            toClient.println("Hello: server is connected " + serverAddress.getLocalHost().toString());
            processClient();
            //   closeStreams();
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error accepting server " + e);
    }
}
```

`processClient()` method:

```
 public void processClient() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Porcessing start");
        String line = fromClient.readLine();
        try
        {
            while (!(line.equals("Bye")))
            {
                textToReceive.append("He: " + line + newline);
                line = fromClient.readLine();
            }
            closeStreams();

        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading from client " + ex);
        }
    }
```

How to correctly enforce the program from running?

**Update 2:** The whole working server class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author S
 */
public class ChatServer extends JFrame
{

    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private InputStream is;
    private OutputStream os;
    private BufferedReader fromClient;
    private PrintWriter toClient;
    private JButton send;
    private JPanel uperPanel;
    private JPanel midPanel;
    private JPanel downPanel;
    private JTextArea textToSend;
    private JTextArea textToReceive;
    private JLabel addressL;
    private final int port = 5555;
    private boolean idle = false;
    private int timeout = 3000;
    public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    private ChatServer()
    {
        this.setGUI();
        this.setVisible(true);
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            this.run();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent)
            {
                idle = true;
                closeStreams();
                socket = null;
                serverSocket = null;
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("System is running");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client accepted on server side");
                openStreams();
                toClient.println("Hello: server is connected " + serverAddress.getLocalHost().toString());
                processClient();
                //   closeStreams();
            }
        } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ee)
        {

            closeStreams();
            System.out.println(ee);


        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error accepting server " + e);
        }

    }

    public void processClient() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Porcessing start");
        String line = fromClient.readLine();
        try
        {
            while (!(line.equals("Bye")))
            {
                textToReceive.append("He: " + line + newline);
                line = fromClient.readLine();
            }
            closeStreams();

        } catch (IOException ex)
        {

            System.out.println("Error reading from client " + ex);

        }
    }

    private void setGUI()
    {

        this.setSize(375, 314);


        send = new JButton("send");

        try
        {
            addressL = new JLabel("My Server address: " + serverAddress.getLocalHost().toString()
                    + "  Port: " + this.port);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown Host problem " + e);
        }

        textToReceive = new JTextArea(12, 30);
        textToReceive.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane recievedScrolledText = new JScrollPane(textToReceive);
        recievedScrolledText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textToReceive.setEditable(false);


        textToSend = new JTextArea(3, 25);
        textToSend.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane sentScrolledText = new JScrollPane(textToSend);
        sentScrolledText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textToSend.setEditable(true);

        uperPanel = new JPanel();
        midPanel = new JPanel();
        downPanel = new JPanel();

        uperPanel.add(addressL);


        midPanel.add(recievedScrolledText);
        downPanel.add(sentScrolledText);
        downPanel.add(send);

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.add(uperPanel, "North");
        c.add(midPanel, "Center");
        c.add(downPanel, "South");

        send.addActionListener(new ButtonWatch());
        textToSend.addKeyListener(new KeyWatch());
    }

    private void openStreams() throws IOException
    {

        is = socket.getInputStream();
        fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        toClient = new PrintWriter(os, true);
        System.out.println("open stream is open on server");
    }

    private void closeStreams()
    {
        try
        {

            if ((toClient != null) && (os != null)
                    && (fromClient != null) && (is != null)
                    && (fromClient != null) && (socket != null))
            {
                toClient.close();
                os.close();
                fromClient.close();
                is.close();
                socket.close();
            }


        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem closing streams " + ex);
        }
    }

    private class KeyWatch extends KeyAdapter
    {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                String line = textToSend.getText();
                textToSend.setText("");
                toClient.println(line);
                textToReceive.append("You: " + line + newline);
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
            }
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private class ButtonWatch implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object buttonPressed = e.getSource();

            if (buttonPressed == send)
            {
                String line = textToSend.getText();
                textToSend.setText("");
                toClient.println(line);
                textToReceive.append("You: " + line + newline);

                System.out.println("send to client " + line);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ChatServer s = new ChatServer();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now how to terminate it after closing.

Comment: Demonstrate your loop. Generally, the proper way would be to hold a reference to the Thread that runs the loop and call `Thread.interrupt`, where the `run` method checks the `Thread.interrupted()` status regularly.

Comment: infiny loop is caused in code lines that you didn't shows, I bet that code line 57th. or/and with 875th., for better help sooner post an SSCCE, demonstrating your a.m. issue, short, runnable, compilable, about closing Socket, and empty JFrame otherwise everything here are shots to the dark,

Comment: against whatever from answers here, most (closing by using methods implemented in APIs) of workers threads and connection, Socker, RMI, cobra .... are asynchronous, then there no guaranteee depends of, hide JFrame and then do somenting with terminate/close/expire/whatever, but no issue with Socket by default, OPs mistake isnt posted nor described

Comment: I update my question, if you know how to make it terminate just tell. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop program running infinite loop on close GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651654/how-to-stop-program-running-infinite-loop-on-close-gui)

Answer (score 1):

**-** Well its better to use `Executor` to span the thread.

**-** Then use `cancel(true)` with `submit()` method to interrupt this particular thread.

**-** If you want to go with `Thread` directly then you can use `interrupt()` or `interrupted()` method to interrupt the `thread`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your server loop to be *not* infinite.

```
volatile boolean runFlag = true;
while (runFlag) {
  //do server stuff
}
```

and get your closing method to flag the server to stop.

```
this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
    System.out.println("Close operation server done");
    toClient.println("Bye");
    closeStreams();
    runFlag = false;
  }
});
```

You might want to move the stream closing stuff to after the main server loop so that any stuff that is in progress gets finished and you don't interrupt anything currently in progress.