# How to stop program running infinite loop on close GUI

Tags: java, sockets, terminate

I have a simple program for server/client communication using sockets.
The server class contains `run()` method, this method has infinite loop to wait for socket acceptance.

Any way, I wrote a code in the constructor to do termination for processing on close,

```
 this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        System.out.println("Close operation server done");
        toClient.println("Bye");
        closeStreams();
        socket = null;
        serverSocket = null;
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

When I read the API for the [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) `windowClosing(WindowEvent e)` it says:

> Invoked when a window is in the process of being closed. The close
>   operation can be overridden at this point.

It says **when** a window is in the process of being closed. But the loop inside the run() method still gaining the control, and will not finish due to the logic of the program, so the window will not be closed (actually the GUI is closed) but the processing is still working behind the scenes.

How to correctly enforce the program from running?

The whole working server class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ChatServer extends JFrame
{

    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private InputStream is;
    private OutputStream os;
    private BufferedReader fromClient;
    private PrintWriter toClient;
    private JButton send;
    private JPanel uperPanel;
    private JPanel midPanel;
    private JPanel downPanel;
    private JTextArea textToSend;
    private JTextArea textToReceive;
    private JLabel addressL;
    private final int port = 5555;
    private boolean idle = false;
    private int timeout = 3000;
    public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    private ChatServer()
    {
        this.setGUI();
        this.setVisible(true);
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            this.run();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent)
            {
                idle = true;
                closeStreams();
                socket = null;
                serverSocket = null;
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("System is running");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client accepted on server side");
                openStreams();
                toClient.println("Hello: server is connected " + serverAddress.getLocalHost().toString());
                processClient();
                //   closeStreams();
            }
        } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ee)
        {

            closeStreams();
            System.out.println(ee);


        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error accepting server " + e);
        }

    }

    public void processClient() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Porcessing start");
        String line = fromClient.readLine();
        try
        {
            while (!(line.equals("Bye")))
            {
                textToReceive.append("He: " + line + newline);
                line = fromClient.readLine();
            }
            closeStreams();

        } catch (IOException ex)
        {

            System.out.println("Error reading from client " + ex);

        }
    }

    private void setGUI()
    {

        this.setSize(375, 314);


        send = new JButton("send");

        try
        {
            addressL = new JLabel("My Server address: " + serverAddress.getLocalHost().toString()
                    + "  Port: " + this.port);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown Host problem " + e);
        }

        textToReceive = new JTextArea(12, 30);
        textToReceive.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane recievedScrolledText = new JScrollPane(textToReceive);
        recievedScrolledText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textToReceive.setEditable(false);


        textToSend = new JTextArea(3, 25);
        textToSend.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane sentScrolledText = new JScrollPane(textToSend);
        sentScrolledText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textToSend.setEditable(true);

        uperPanel = new JPanel();
        midPanel = new JPanel();
        downPanel = new JPanel();

        uperPanel.add(addressL);


        midPanel.add(recievedScrolledText);
        downPanel.add(sentScrolledText);
        downPanel.add(send);

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.add(uperPanel, "North");
        c.add(midPanel, "Center");
        c.add(downPanel, "South");

        send.addActionListener(new ButtonWatch());
        textToSend.addKeyListener(new KeyWatch());
    }

    private void openStreams() throws IOException
    {

        is = socket.getInputStream();
        fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        toClient = new PrintWriter(os, true);
        System.out.println("open stream is open on server");
    }

    private void closeStreams()
    {
        try
        {

            if ((toClient != null) && (os != null)
                    && (fromClient != null) && (is != null)
                    && (fromClient != null) && (socket != null))
            {
                toClient.close();
                os.close();
                fromClient.close();
                is.close();
                socket.close();
            }


        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem closing streams " + ex);
        }
    }

    private class KeyWatch extends KeyAdapter
    {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                String line = textToSend.getText();
                textToSend.setText("");
                toClient.println(line);
                textToReceive.append("You: " + line + newline);
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
            }
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private class ButtonWatch implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object buttonPressed = e.getSource();

            if (buttonPressed == send)
            {
                String line = textToSend.getText();
                textToSend.setText("");
                toClient.println(line);
                textToReceive.append("You: " + line + newline);

                System.out.println("send to client " + line);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ChatServer s = new ChatServer();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now how to terminate it correctly after clicking the (x) closing icon.

Comment: I am sorry. I repeated my question because the previous one was not clear/specific, and so answers don't belong to my problem. I flagged my previous question and asked deletion.

Comment: Post only relevant code, do you really expect I will read all this?

Comment: while (true) without a break or a condition priceless !

Comment: Have you looked at [setDefaultCloseOperation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing[/JFramesetDefaultCloseOperationintoption.htm) and a CloseListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) window event handler?

Comment: I don't expect that @mouseevent. it has no errors, I just want to close the window and make things terminate. the `run()` method gain the control and doesn't  release so how to interrupt it and get things closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Thread` and set it as a `daemon` thread. Here I changed the first few lines, of your code:

```
public class ChatServer extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    private ChatServer()
    {
        this.setGUI();
        this.setVisible(true);
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Thread accept = new Thread(this);
            accept.setDaemon(true);
            accept.start();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: No thread used, I want to interrupt `run()` method so and enable things to be closed

Comment: @SalehFeek Well, it's the `main` thread, used here, see edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to solve it all the day. Your solution is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: ,the previous answer (before edit) is the working one for my code. I tried the code (after edit) it doesn't work, it gives an exception. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` I am using the code before edit. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 2):

ALSO:

Have you looked at [setDefaultCloseOperation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing%5b/JFramesetDefaultCloseOperationintoption.htm) and a [CloseListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) window event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Close you server socket `serverSocket.close()` in `windowClosing` handler. This will throw `SocketException` in your accept loop and interrupt it. You can catch it and process to make graceful shutdown.